# awk script to cut/paste a string in a file

Tags: awk

i got a file formatted like that : (each space = tab separator)

```
NB551027:767:H73JMAFX2:1:11101:5356:1093:AATGT+GTGTA blabla LASTTAG
```

i want to cut/paste the :AATGT+GTGTA part at the end of the line, with a tab separator to get

```
NB551027:767:H73JMAFX2:1:11101:5356:1093 blabla LASTTAG RX:Z:AATGT+GTGTA
```

important precision : i want the last string after the last ':' of the first instance to be copy paste,  (included the ':') regardless of the size of the string (it can be AAAA, or AAAA+GGGG, etc.)

i used the following awk script :

```
awk '/^@/ {print;next} {N=split($1,n,":"); print $0 "\tRX:Z:" n[N] ; sub("[:]"n[N],"") ; print $0}'
```

my problem is that the original line is still there so i got this result

```
NB551027:767:H73JMAFX2:1:11101:5356:1093:AATGT+GTGTA blabla LASTTAG
NB551027:767:H73JMAFX2:1:11101:5356:1093 blabla LASTTAG RX:Z:AATGT+GTGTA
```

basically i don't know how to redirect the results in a new file (or overwrite the original file) with awk. A bash script will also be a good solution for me. Thks for your help

Edit : forget to mention that i had to exclude the lines beginning with @ : the script should not applied to thoses lines. (it's a bam file for NGS datas, the header lines should not be changed)

The file look like this

```
@SQ     SN:chrY LN:59373566
@RG     ID:1    PL:ILLUMINA     PU:PU   LB:001  SM:TeCoriell
@PG     ID:MarkDuplicates       VN:2.23.7       CL:MarkDuplicates BARCODE_TAG=RX DUPLEX_UMI=true INPUT=[TeCoriell.bwamem.bam OUTPUT=/TeCoriell/TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.recalibration.realignment.bam METRICS_FILE=/TeCoriell/TeCoriell.bwamem.bam PN:MarkDuplicates
@PG     ID:bwa  PN:bwa  VN:0.7.17-r1188 CL:/tools/bwa/current/bin/bwa mem -C -M -t 4 -R @RG\tID:1\tPL:ILLUMINA\tPU:PU\tLB:001\tSM:TeCoriell TeCoriell.R1.fastq.gz TeCoriell.R2.fastq.gz
@PG     ID:samtools     PN:samtools     PP:bwa  VN:1.11 
@PG     ID:samtools.1   PN:samtools     PP:samtools     VN:1.11
@PG     ID:GATK PrintReads      VN:3.8-1-0-gf15c1c3ef   CL:readGroup=null platform=null number=-1 sample_file=[] sample_name=[] simplify=false no_pg_tag=false
@PG     ID:samtools.2   PN:samtools     PP:samtools.1   VN:1.11 CL:samtools sort -o TeCoriell.bwamem.bam -l 5 -T TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.bam.SAMTOOLS_PREFIX -@ 4 TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.bam
@PG     ID:samtools.3   PN:samtools     PP:samtools.2   VN:1.11 CL:samtools view -h TeCoriell.bwamem.bam
NB551027:724:HTWHHAFXY:3:21602:20054:7507:CACTC-CCGTC   371     chr1    10257   0       2H48M59H        chr7    128036692       0       ACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCCATCCCCACCCCCA        AEEF>86/>G)-,F><)C;
>/G7D,FF28<.1FFGDAF>F@BEECA4>   SA:Z:chr7,128036692,+,76M33S,60,0;      BC:Z:TGCCACCA+GAGCAGCC  MC:Z:76M33H     BD:Z:MJOMLMMJNMLLLJOMLMMIOMLMMIOMLLMJJMOOMJJMNNKKJMMM   MD:Z:36A5A5     PG:Z:MarkDuplicates     RG:
Z:1     BI:Z:RNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNNQSSQNNQQRNNNQQQ   NM:i:2  OQ:Z:EEEEE<</AE///EA</EAA/EAE/EE6AA//EEEEEEAEAEEEEE/E   AS:i:38 XS:i:38
NB551027:724:HTWHHAFXY:2:11110:2230:8695:AGTCT-AAAGT    163     chr1    15596   0       113M    =       15596   113     CAGGAAGGAGCCATAGCCCAGGCAGGAGGGCTGAGGACCTCTGGTGGCGGCCCAGGGCTTCCAGCATGTGCCCTAGGGGAAGCAGGGGCCA
GCTGGCAAGAGCAGGGGGTGGG  =>BB?@F>AGCBAB>GCBCBGFDBGFAGFFDEGAG>@DCEFEFEBGECAECBBAFEECDCEBA@CABFAFCB8D>FEEE@A@CA@DE?BA9E2CE>B@:E??B@?>CDD;DC/       BC:Z:TGGCACCA+GAGCAGCA  MC:Z:113M       BD:Z:MMOONPOOMONKLNLLMJILNN
JMNNLNNIKMMNNNLMLLLLLMLLLJLJJJILNNJKNMLMMONMNOLMLJJMLMOJJMOMNNOOJJKKMONNLMKNNNOONNNOJJJMMMJ     MD:Z:113        PG:Z:MarkDuplicates     RG:Z:1  BI:Z:QQRQQQSQQRSPPSQRSPLPRQQSRQQRQNQSSRRQQRQSQRSQRQQQRMQPLPRQNQSRQT
PRSSSSQQSPLSRRQNNQQSSSRQNNQPPRSSSQQSQSRRSSRQNNNRQQN     NM:i:0  OQ:Z:EEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEE<EEEEEEEEAEEAEEAEEAE6EEAEEAEEAEEAAEEEAEE/  AS:i:113        XS:i:113
```

i should get this result

```
@SQ     SN:chrY LN:59373566
@RG     ID:1    PL:ILLUMINA     PU:PU   LB:001  SM:TeCoriell
@PG     ID:MarkDuplicates       VN:2.23.7       CL:MarkDuplicates BARCODE_TAG=RX DUPLEX_UMI=true INPUT=[TeCoriell.bwamem.bam OUTPUT=/TeCoriell/TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.recalibration.realignment.bam METRICS_FILE=/TeCoriell/TeCoriell.bwamem.bam PN:MarkDuplicates
@PG     ID:bwa  PN:bwa  VN:0.7.17-r1188 CL:/tools/bwa/current/bin/bwa mem -C -M -t 4 -R @RG\tID:1\tPL:ILLUMINA\tPU:PU\tLB:001\tSM:TeCoriell TeCoriell.R1.fastq.gz TeCoriell.R2.fastq.gz
@PG     ID:samtools     PN:samtools     PP:bwa  VN:1.11 
@PG     ID:samtools.1   PN:samtools     PP:samtools     VN:1.11
@PG     ID:GATK PrintReads      VN:3.8-1-0-gf15c1c3ef   CL:readGroup=null platform=null number=-1 sample_file=[] sample_name=[] simplify=false no_pg_tag=false
@PG     ID:samtools.2   PN:samtools     PP:samtools.1   VN:1.11 CL:samtools sort -o TeCoriell.bwamem.bam -l 5 -T TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.bam.SAMTOOLS_PREFIX -@ 4 TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.bam
@PG     ID:samtools.3   PN:samtools     PP:samtools.2   VN:1.11 CL:samtools view -h TeCoriell.bwamem.bam
NB551027:724:HTWHHAFXY:3:21602:20054:7507   371     chr1    10257   0       2H48M59H        chr7    128036692       0       ACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCCATCCCCACCCCCA        AEEF>86/>G)-,F><)C;
>/G7D,FF28<.1FFGDAF>F@BEECA4>   SA:Z:chr7,128036692,+,76M33S,60,0;      BC:Z:TGCCACCA+GAGCAGCC  MC:Z:76M33H     BD:Z:MJOMLMMJNMLLLJOMLMMIOMLMMIOMLLMJJMOOMJJMNNKKJMMM   MD:Z:36A5A5     PG:Z:MarkDuplicates     RG:
Z:1     BI:Z:RNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNNQSSQNNQQRNNNQQQ   NM:i:2  OQ:Z:EEEEE<</AE///EA</EAA/EAE/EE6AA//EEEEEEAEAEEEEE/E   AS:i:38 XS:i:38 RX:Z:CACTC-CCGTC
NB551027:724:HTWHHAFXY:2:11110:2230:8695    163     chr1    15596   0       113M    =       15596   113     CAGGAAGGAGCCATAGCCCAGGCAGGAGGGCTGAGGACCTCTGGTGGCGGCCCAGGGCTTCCAGCATGTGCCCTAGGGGAAGCAGGGGCCA
GCTGGCAAGAGCAGGGGGTGGG  =>BB?@F>AGCBAB>GCBCBGFDBGFAGFFDEGAG>@DCEFEFEBGECAECBBAFEECDCEBA@CABFAFCB8D>FEEE@A@CA@DE?BA9E2CE>B@:E??B@?>CDD;DC/       BC:Z:TGGCACCA+GAGCAGCA  MC:Z:113M       BD:Z:MMOONPOOMONKLNLLMJILNN
JMNNLNNIKMMNNNLMLLLLLMLLLJLJJJILNNJKNMLMMONMNOLMLJJMLMOJJMOMNNOOJJKKMONNLMKNNNOONNNOJJJMMMJ     MD:Z:113        PG:Z:MarkDuplicates     RG:Z:1  BI:Z:QQRQQQSQQRSPPSQRSPLPRQQSRQQRQNQSSRRQQRQSQRSQRQQQRMQPLPRQNQSRQT
PRSSSSQQSPLSRRQNNQQSSSRQNNQPPRSSSQQSQSRRSSRQNNNRQQN     NM:i:0  OQ:Z:EEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEE<EEEEEEEEAEEAEEAEEAE6EEAEEAEEAEEAAEEEAEE/  AS:i:113        XS:i:113 RX:Z:AGTCT-AAAGT
```

Comment: i edited it, hope it's clearer.

Comment: each line for the body part begin with NB551027:724:HTWHHAFXY:3:21602:20054:7507:CACTC-CCGTC and the :CACTC-CCGTC should be append at the end of each sequence after the last tag (XS:i:XX RX:Z:CACTC-CCGTC. Only one ":" should separate the Z from the CACTC-CCGTC i corrected it

Comment: each sequence part (beginning with NB... and finishing with the last tag part XS:etc) is a unique line

Comment: I am not asking about uniqueness. I just want to confirm that there are line breaks in each record that starts with `NB` and ends with `XS:i:38`

Comment: yes i mean each line as decribed end with a line break

Comment: ok then can we assume that each record always starts with `NB`?

Comment: for the sequence part yes, (for the header part it's @ (with several differents tags after))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|\n)(@|NB)' -F "[[:space:]]+" -v OFS='\t' '(n=split($1, a, /:/)) > 1 {sub(/:[^:\t]+\t/, OFS); sub(/\n$/, ""); $0 = $0 OFS "RX:Z:" a[n]} {ORS=RT} 1; END {print "\n"}' file

@SQ SN:chrY LN:59373566
@RG ID:1    PL:ILLUMINA PU:PU   LB:001  SM:TeCoriell
@PG ID:MarkDuplicates   VN:2.23.7   CL:MarkDuplicates   BARCODE_TAG=RX  DUPLEX_UMI=true INPUT=[TeCoriell.bwamem.bam OUTPUT=/TeCoriell/TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.recalibration.realignment.bam   METRICS_FILE=/TeCoriell/TeCoriell.bwamem.bam    PN:MarkDuplicates
@PG ID:bwa  PN:bwa  VN:0.7.17-r1188 CL:/tools/bwa/current/bin/bwa   mem -C  -M  -t  4   -R  @RG\tID:1\tPL:ILLUMINA\tPU:PU\tLB:001\tSM:TeCoriell TeCoriell.R1.fastq.gz   TeCoriell.R2.fastq.gz
@PG ID:samtools PN:samtools PP:bwa  VN:1.11
@PG ID:samtools.1   PN:samtools PP:samtools VN:1.11
@PG ID:GATK PrintReads  VN:3.8-1-0-gf15c1c3ef   CL:readGroup=null   platform=null   number=-1   sample_file=[]  sample_name=[]  simplify=false  no_pg_tag=false
@PG ID:samtools.2   PN:samtools PP:samtools.1   VN:1.11 CL:samtools sort    -o  TeCoriell.bwamem.bam    -l  5   -T  TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.bam.SAMTOOLS_PREFIX   -@  4   TeCoriell.bwamem.compress.bam
@PG ID:samtools.3   PN:samtools PP:samtools.2   VN:1.11 CL:samtools view    -h  TeCoriell.bwamem.bam
NB551026:723:HTWHHAFXY:3:21602:20054:7507   371 chr1    10257   0   2H48M59H    chr7    128036692   0   ACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCCATCCCCACCCCCA    AEEF>86/>G)-,F><)C;
>/G7D,FF28<.1FFGDAF>F@BEECA4>   SA:Z:chr7,128036692,+,76M33S,60,0;  BC:Z:TGCCACCA+GAGCAGCC  MC:Z:76M33H BD:Z:MJOMLMMJNMLLLJOMLMMIOMLMMIOMLLMJJMOOMJJMNNKKJMMM   MD:Z:36A5A5 PG:Z:MarkDuplicates RG:
Z:1 BI:Z:RNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNQRQRRNNQSSQNNQQRNNNQQQ   NM:i:2  OQ:Z:EEEEE<</AE///EA</EAA/EAE/EE6AA//EEEEEEAEAEEEEE/E   AS:i:38 XS:i:38 RX:Z:CACTC-CCGTC
NB551027:724:HTWHHAFXY:2:11110:2230:8695    163 chr1    15596   0   113M    =   15596   113 CAGGAAGGAGCCATAGCCCAGGCAGGAGGGCTGAGGACCTCTGGTGGCGGCCCAGGGCTTCCAGCATGTGCCCTAGGGGAAGCAGGGGCCA
GCTGGCAAGAGCAGGGGGTGGG  =>BB?@F>AGCBAB>GCBCBGFDBGFAGFFDEGAG>@DCEFEFEBGECAECBBAFEECDCEBA@CABFAFCB8D>FEEE@A@CA@DE?BA9E2CE>B@:E??B@?>CDD;DC/   BC:Z:TGGCACCA+GAGCAGCA  MC:Z:113M   BD:Z:MMOONPOOMONKLNLLMJILNN
JMNNLNNIKMMNNNLMLLLLLMLLLJLJJJILNNJKNMLMMONMNOLMLJJMLMOJJMOMNNOOJJKKMONNLMKNNNOONNNOJJJMMMJ MD:Z:113    PG:Z:MarkDuplicates RG:Z:1  BI:Z:QQRQQQSQQRSPPSQRSPLPRQQSRQQRQNQSSRRQQRQSQRSQRQQQRMQPLPRQNQSRQT
PRSSSSQQSPLSRRQNNQQSSSRQNNQPPRSSSQQSQSRRSSRQNNNRQQN NM:i:0  OQ:Z:EEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEE<EEEEEEEEAEEAEEAEEAE6EEAEEAEEAEEAAEEEAEE/  AS:i:113    XS:i:113    RX:Z:AGTCT-AAAGT
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|\n)(@|NB)' -F "[[:space:]]+" -v OFS='\t' '
(n=split($1, a, /:/)) > 1 {
   sub(/:[^:\t]+\t/, OFS)
   sub(/\n$/, "")
   $0 = $0 OFS "RX:Z:" a[n]
}
{
   ORS=RT
}
1;
END {
   print "\n"
}' file
```

Comment: thks for the answer, i forget to mention that i need to exclude all the lines beginning with @ in my files

Comment: not totally working, i think the header part is not kept in the output file, so the result is not formatted correctly and not "readable"

Comment: the header part is pasted on the output file, but no change whatsoever occured in the sequence part

Comment: Same results, no change, the header is correct but the sequence part did not changed. I tried without the specific editor (samtools) to see if it can be the problem, but no difference either. Sed and awk script either.

Comment: another last little problem, i'm struggling to add the script into a proper awk file, i replace the ' with " for the RS/OFS definition (and without the -v option) but there's still errors

Comment: I believe when using `".."` then \ should become \\ in those variables

Comment: thks, still not working in a script file, but i manage to use it directly with a pipe so it's good for me

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{x=$1; sub(/.*:/,"",x); sub(/:[^:\t]*\t/,"\t"); print $0 "\tRX:Z:" x}' file
NB551027:767:H73JMAFX2:1:11101:5356:1093        blabla  LASTTAG RX:Z:AATGT+GTGTA
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/^@/{ next }
match($0,/.*:/){
  part1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  part2=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  match(part2,/[^ ]*/)
  print part1 substr(part2,RSTART+RLENGTH) "\tRX:Z:" substr(part2,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}' Input_file
```

Comment: thks for the answer, i forget to mention that i need to exclude all the lines beginning with @ in my file. Also i add { } between the several commands, my awk version output a syntax error if not

Comment: @Toml, ok please try my edited code now and let me know how it goes?

Comment: same answer as above not totally working, i think the header part is not kept in the output file, so the result is not formatted correctly and not "readable"

Comment: @Toml, Like anubhava sir mentioned in comments, your samples of input are NOT clear, please make them clear, thank you.

Comment: i update it, all the lines begining with @ should be paste on the new file, without changes

Comment: @Toml, its not clear, so lines starting with `@` should be simply printed to new file? And other than lines which are NOT starting with `@` your logic should be applied? Please confirm once.

Comment: Yes that right. Thks for your patience, i should ne more specific next time

Comment: @Toml, ok how about my current(edited) solution let me know how it goes?

Comment: it pasted only lines beginning with "@PG", but it's the lines added by the tool to edit my file (samtools) ; each edit of the file is recorded in the "@PG" header ; so it didn't seemed that the script paste the original header

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu` awk, you might also use [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) with 3 capture groups.

The third param `a` contains the group values which you can access by index.

In the replacement you can reorder them and add `"\tRX:Z:"` between group 3 and 2.

```
gawk 'match($0, /(.*):([^:\t]+)(\t.*)/, a) {print a[1]a[3]"\tRX:Z:"a[2]}' file
```

The pattern matches

- `(.*):` Group 1, match before the last `:`
- `([^:\t]+)` Group 2, match 1 or more occurrences of any char except `:` or a tab
- `(\t.*)` Group 3, match a tab and the rest of the line

Output

```
NB551027:767:H73JMAFX2:1:11101:5356:1093    blabla  LASTTAG RX:Z:AATGT+GTGTA
```